# OAuth1 Server aupport for Jersey 2 based RESTful web services

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth, jersey, jersey-2.0

1. How to enable OAuth1 Server support for Jersey 2.9 based RESTful web services? Is there any example project demonstrating  the required features? The user (Android App) should get HTTP 401, if he does not include authenticated token in request header.

See reference docs: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e10946

> First step in enabling Jersey OAuth 1 support is to register a
>   OAuth1ServerFeature instance initialized with an instance of
>   OAuth1Provider. Additionally, you may configure the Request Token URI
>   and Access Token URI - the endpoints accessible on the OAuth server
>   that issue Request and Access Tokens. These endpoints are defined in
>   the OAuth 1 specification and are contacted as part of the OAuth
>   authorization flow.

1. Should I use OAuth1 server support for securing Jersey 2.9 based web services? Is there any other better library that can be used to implement token based authentication for Jersey based RESTful web services?

Comment: Old thread I know, but having figured it out myself I posted an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798855/enabling-oauth1-support-on-a-jersey-jax-rs-web-service/35475593#35475593