# Where is consumer key param in Jersey's OAuth1 API?

Tags: oauth, jersey

I'm trying to implement OAuth1 with Jersey.

In [OAuth1Provider.java](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/security/oauth1-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/OAuth1Provider.java), there are two methods return `OAuth1Token` with given token value.

- [OAuth1Token getRequestToken(String token)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/OAuth1Provider.html#getRequestToken(java.lang.String))
- [OAuth1Token getAccessToken(String token)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/OAuth1Provider.html#getAccessToken(java.lang.String))

Both methods mention `by the consumer key and token value`.

Where is the `consumer key` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake in javadoc. You can look at source code for `OAuth1Provider` default implementation [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/security/oauth1-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/DefaultOAuth1Provider.java) and see that there is no consumer key usages, just lookup by token value.
Also, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35475593/5717245).